# unable to destroy activity when trying stop not running thread

Tags: java, android

I am bit confused with threads i made. I have several threads running, and some activity creates and cleans a new thread. So now when I try to exit application I use aboart. I checked/ when thread is running its closed fine. But when not I get errors and "... 11 more"... any Idea what am i doing wrong?

```
    public void run() {
    while (abort_) {
        //doeing stuff
        } 
    }


synchronized public void abort() {
    abort_ = true;
    if (ioio_ != null) {
        ioio_.disconnect();
    }
}
```

When Main() is destroid:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Start_settings.stopSetThread();
    bool = false; //stop screanThrea
        if(ioio_thread_.isAlive()){
              ioio_thread_.abort();
        }
}
```

so when onDestroy() method is called its throuws:
UPDATED i missed the line:

```
W/dalvikvm(8672): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)



E/AndroidRuntime(8191): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(8191): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {android.io/android.io.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(8191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2676)
E/AndroidRuntime(8191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2694)
E/AndroidRuntime(8191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(8191):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
E/AndroidRuntime(8191):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(8191):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(8191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
E/AndroidRuntime(8191):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(8191):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(8191):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
E/AndroidRuntime(8191):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
E/AndroidRuntime(8191):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(8191): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(8191):     at android.kvisio.Main.onDestroy(Main.java:364)
E/AndroidRuntime(8191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
E/AndroidRuntime(8191):     ... 11 more
```

I solved my problem by putting flags when thread is started and checking the flags instead of thread.isAlive() method. But my question remains: 
Why when I check not running thread with thread.isAlive() it throws this kind of exceptions?
thanks for your time.

Comment: Debug and check what you are getting null at `line 364`

Comment: @LalitPoptani on line 354 i have `if((ioio_thread_.isAlive()){
              ioio_thread_.abort();
        }`
And at this point ioio_thread_ is never created.

Comment: seems your thread instance is null, put a check on it `if(ioio_thread_ != null){ ....}`

Comment: to be more precise `ioio_thread_.isAlive()` 
when i dont do this check i get same error on `ioio_thread_.abort()`

Comment: same error... I dont understand .isAlive() should do the check but...

Comment: Debug your code and check where you are getting null and what is null.

Comment: @LalitPoptani ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(Thread, Throwable) line: 850 
I get:
W/dalvikvm(8754): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
and then the rest of the errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same error. Do the following:

```
if(ioio_thread_ != null){
   if(ioio_thread_.isAlive()){
   // Do whatever 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    Start_settings.stopSetThread();
    bool = false; //stop screanThrea
    if(!ioio_thread_.isAlive()){
          ioio_thread_.abort();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: my apologies i did not clean the code here.. its only 
`if(ioio_thread_.isAlive()){
              ioio_thread_.abort();
        }`

Comment: so the super.onDestroy() does not related to the null...  i thought it was just now. sorry..

Answer (score 0):

Either `Start_settings` or `ioio_thread_` is null, given the error you are getting.

If you precise the content of the 364th line, you'll see which. It is either never defined, or et to null at some point.

Chances are your thread is null. Test for existence and alive status of thread like this :

```
if(ioio_thread_ != null && ioio_thread_.isAlive()){
    // Do whatever (like aborting)
}
```

Comment: at line 364 is `ioio_thread_.isAlive()` this thread is at that point never created or already destroyed. So to not abort not existing I tried to check ether way `ioio_thread_!=null` or `ioio_thread_.isAlive()` rises this error.